# mouse event while mouse click is held down but not moving , Java awt

Tags: java, jpanel

I want to get mouse event while mouse click is held down but is not moving.
mouseDragged only works while the mouse is moving, but how can I get the event while mouse is not moving.

I'm using  java.awt.event.MouseListener
Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to use `mousePressed(MouseEvent e)` .

Comment: To be clear I'm looking for mouse click while it's held down, mouse pressed only works once, not continuously.

Comment: That's not clear. You should explain why you want to get that result

Comment: Well, you don't receive events when nothing happens.When the mouse is pressed start your stuff (timer or whatever), when it is released stop your stuff.

Comment: @Berger Ah you're right  thank you

Comment: This is how awt events work,  if you want to "keep shooting", start shooting when the mouse is pressed, stop shooting when the mouse is released.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full javadoc for AWT (also for a lot of other api): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

> **void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)**
> Invoked when a mouse button has been pressed on a component.
>
> **void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)**
> Invoked when a mouse button has been released on a component.

Comment: To be clear Im looking for event while mouse click is held down, mouse pressed works only once

Comment: If mouse is pressed and doesn't move, there is no event

Comment: So there is no way to get the mouse event while mouse is pressed continuously

Comment: @amirsoltani No - you will get a "pressed" event, then while you don't get a "dragged" event and until you get a "released" event, the mouse is been pressed in place. It might be easier to provide you with some ideas if we understood the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: In real life, if button is kept pressed and mouse stand still, as an observer, you would say "nothing is happening". Well, in awt, it's the same. If you release the button, you get an event, same if mouse moves.

Comment: @jhamon Is is the same for every other library?

Comment: For Swing, yes. I don't know about JavaFX but it's probably the same

Answer (score 0):

The mouse doesn't detect any events while mouse click is held down and the mouse is in place